# Returning from a express middleware using promise and breaking out from loop returns 404

Tags: node.js, typescript, loops, express, promise

I am trying to return an array of an object(car) from express using database functions used below with stolenCarDb object, but the database functions function perfectly fine
Doing the below returns a 404 with error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

```
router.post("/reportstolen", function (request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: (err?: Error) => void) {
    stolenCarDb.put_car(request.body)
        .then(() => {
            stolenCarDb.get_available_cops()
                .then(cops => {
                    cops.forEach(cop => {
                        stolenCarDb.assign_cop_car(cop._id, request.body._id)
                            .then(() => response.status(201).send(`assgined cop ${cop._id} to car`))
                    })
                })
                .then(() => response.status(201).send("created"))
        })
        .catch(() => response.status(500).send("error"))
        .finally(next)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a response to the user multiple times, which you cannot do.
You should send a response only one time, after all operations completed.

Edit:
If I had to rewrite the code myself, I would use async/await. You could read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Also while rereading your code, I don't see the point of calling `next` in the `finally` block.

**Async/await**

```
router.post("/reportstolen", async function (request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: (err?: Error) => void) {
    try {
      await stolenCarDb.put_car(request.body)
      const cops = await stolenCarDb.get_available_cops(); 
      for (const cop of cops) {
        await stolenCarDb.assign_cop_car(cop._id, request.body._id);
      }

      response.status(201).send("created")
    } catch (err) {
      response.status(500).send("error")
    }
});
```

If you want to display every cop to car addition you can do:

```
router.post("/reportstolen", async function (request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: (err?: Error) => void) {
    try {
      await stolenCarDb.put_car(request.body)
      const cops = await stolenCarDb.get_available_cops();
      for (const cop of cops) {
        await stolenCarDb.assign_cop_car(cop._id, request.body._id);
        res.write(`assgined cop ${cop._id} to car\n`);
      }

      response.status(201).send("created")
    } catch (err) {
      response.status(500).send("error")
    }
});
```

I would also recommend you read this [post](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/) about using promises in loops and why you don't want to use promises in `forEach` loops.

Comment: Could you please rewrite the code to make it work? Because I have tried several modifications none of which have worked